# Dynamic tailwind classes in angular not rendering in Angular component

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

**Context**
I come from a React background and am currently learning Angular.
I have a button component that takes in a prop "color" of either primary | secondary.

The button is being loaded in like this:

`<app-button text="Hello world" color="primary"></app-button>`

The html file looks like this:

```
<button [ngClass]="'btn-'+color">{{text}}</button>
```

The component looks like this :

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

type ButtonType = "primary" | "secondary";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
})

export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() text: string = "Placeholder text"; 
  @Input() color: ButtonType = "secondary";
}
```

css:

```
@layer components {
    .btn {
        @apply inline-flex w-fit bg-red-200 px-4 py-2 rounded-lg; 
    }

    .btn-primary {
        @apply btn bg-black text-white; 
    }

    .btn-secondary {
        @apply btn bg-green-600 text-white; 
    }
}
```

**The problem**

changing prop from primary to secondary does not reflect in the UI.
To ensure it's not a css issue i tried using the btn-primary class directly without dynamic props and this works.

Then I tried the same with secondary.

```
<button [ngClass]="'btn-secondary'">{{text}}</button>
```

From this point on only secondary works when passing it as a prop.

Same case if i manually change it to primary, from this point on only passing in primary as a prop works. It's like it caches one value only and cant dynamically change it..

Comment: @Wongjn so this comes down to tailwind simply not allowing partial classes but it has to be a full class?

Comment: Indeed, it comes down to Tailwind not allowing partial classes – it has to be a full class.